# How much memory will a char in CUDA actually take?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

In my CUDA kernel, I need a lot of indexes, all in the range of less than 256. To save memory and memory bandwith, I plan to put these indexes in `char` instead of `int`.

Will this actually save me memory or does CUDA automatically use a 32 or 64 bit memory place for one `char`?

(Memory coalescing is not an issue here, since the indexes are the same for all kernels.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char itself will take one byte. CUDA is not a weird system, so it's the regular 8-bit byte. Whether that's a saving depends on context. If you have those char indices in an array, there will be no padding between them and you'll save time. If each char is part of a structure and sandwiched between two integers, you *will* have padding (CUDA aligns integers).

Comment: I guess that will hold as long as the chars are in global or shared memory, but when i explicitly define some char variables (which will be bound to a register) or when i do calculations (which will also happen in a register), one char uses a full register. Is this correct?

Comment: @Michael Nvidia GPUs only have 32bit wide registers

Comment: One `char` variable, stored in a register on a CPU, uses a whole CPU register also.  There's nothing particularly special here.